# Pandas column filled with arrays, concatenate values inside arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, concatenation

I have a data frame with tokenized words, and another dataframe with the detokenized version of those words. I need to detokenize the words so I can then merge the two data frames.
I tried using join and other methods but it doesn't seem to work :

this is the original dataframe with tokenized values

```
0       ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'c', '2', '...
1       ['[CLS]', 'C', 'O', 'c', '1', 'c', 'c', 'c', '...
2       ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', '...
3       ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'c', '2', '...
4       ['[CLS]', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', '1', 'n', 'c', '...
                              ...                        
5024    ['[CLS]', 'C', 'c', '1', 'c', 'c', '(', 'I', '...
5025    ['[CLS]', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'c', '1', 'c', 'c', '...
5026    ['[CLS]', 'C', 'O', 'c', '1', 'c', 'n', 'c', '...
5027    ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', '...
5028    ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', '...
```

I want each of the rows to be concatenated so each row looks like a chemical compound like this

```
ex : 0 cc1coN[@@305]
```

I have tried

```
b = df['tokens']
b = pd.DataFrame(b.values.tolist())
b.columns = ['values']

b = b.replace('CLS','', regex=True)
b = b.replace('SEP','', regex=True)
b = b.replace('\[]','', regex=True)

b = b.replace(',','', regex=True)
```

I know using ','.join should work but it instead outputs :

```
b = df['tokens']
b = b.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)) 

0       [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',N,',,, ,',1,',...
1       [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',O,',,, ,',c,',...
2       [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',N,',,, ,',1,',...
3       [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',N,',,, ,',1,',...
4       [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',C,',,, ,',C,',...
                              ...                        
5024    [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',c,',,, ,',1,',...
5025    [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',C,',,, ,',O,',...
5026    [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',O,',,, ,',c,',...
5027    [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',N,',,, ,',1,',...
5028    [,',[,C,L,S,],',,, ,',C,',,, ,',N,',,, ,',1,',...
Name: tokens, Length: 5029, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you can simplify by replacing the string elements you don`t need. No need to use join. I created a new column to apply the changes but it is not necessary.

```
#Create a new column, not needed but keeps track of changes
df['new_col']=df['tokens']

#replace strings
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].replace('CLS','', regex=True)
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].replace('SEP','', regex=True)


#Replace quotes, space, commas then brackets
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].replace(('\'|\s|\,|\[|\]'),'', regex=True)
```

Which creates the result of:

```
    tokens                                          new_col
0   ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'c', '2',]   CN1CCc2
1   ['[CLS]', 'C', 'O', 'c', '1', 'c', 'c', 'c',]   COc1ccc
2   ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', ]  CN1CCNC
3   ['[CLS]', 'C', 'N', '1', 'C', 'C', 'c', '2',]   CN1CCc2
4   ['[CLS]', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', '1', 'n', 'c',]   CCCc1nc
```

Update:

```
#Create a new column, not needed but keeps track of changes
df['new_col']=df['tokens']

#replace strings
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].replace('\[CLS]','', regex=True)
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].replace('\[SEP]','', regex=True)


#Replace quotes, space, commas 
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].replace(('\'|\s|\,'),'', regex=True)
```

Remove the brackets from the symbol replace line and add them to line replacing the CLS, SEP strings. (\ is used to escape special characters for regex)

https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python

Comment: thank you!! what would I do if I need to keep some of the brackets? I only want the brackets with [CLS] and [SEP] gone but not any others

Comment: Updated answer above, you simply remove the brackets from the replace statement and add them to replace statement for the strings.

Comment: wouldn't that still leave the brackets in the front and end of the string?

Comment: You can use the regex to target only the brackets at the beginning  and end of the string if you don't want them by reading the documentation.

https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python